# AttributeError on init after overriding __setattr__ in base class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a base class implemented as below:

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        self.attrmap = {
            'x': ['gridpos', 'x']
        }

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        attrmap = self.attrmap
        model = self.model
        while len(attrmap[key]) > 1:
            model = model[attrmap[key].pop()]
        model[attrmap[key].pop()] = value
```

And a subclass as implemented below:

```
class Sub(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        row_path = Path('row.json')
        with open(template_path / row_path) as file:
            self.model = json.load(file)
```

For some reason, when I instantiate the sub class

```
sub = Sub()
```

I receive the following error message:

```
AttributeError: 'Sub' object has no attribute 'attrmap'
```

Any ideas for why this could be occurring? I've tried to find similar StackOverflow posts, but have so far not been able to resolve the issue.

Comment: `self.attrmap = ` in your `__init__` triggers a call to your `__setattr__` method, which assumes `self.attrmap` already exists. Either alter your `__setattr__` to account for it, or bypass `__setattr__` in your `__init__` method.

Answer (score 1):

When your `Base.__init__` method executes:

```
self.attrmap = ...
```

this triggers a call to your `__setattr__` method; and that method assumes that `self.attrmap` already exists.

Either alter your `__setattr__` to account for it, or bypass `__setattr__` in your `__init__` method:

```
def __init__(self):
    # bypass this class's __setattr__ method.
    object.__setattr__(self, 'attrmap', {'x': ['gridpos', 'x']})
```